# Poisson process elapsed time distribution

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

We know in a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda$, the time between two consecutive occurrence is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$, and as a result it is memoryless.

We are interested in finding the density function for the elapsed time. Indeed we are looking at the process at a time, what is the density of the time difference of the previous occurrence and the time that we are looking at the process?

I have the following explanation, but I cannot figure out, where am I wrong.

Let $T_e$ be the **elapsed** time, $T_w$, the time we should **wait** for the next occurrence, and $T$ be the time between two occurrence. Then obviously we have 
$$T_e=T-T_w\Rightarrow \mathbb{E}[T_e]=\mathbb{E}[T]-\mathbb{E}[T_w]=\frac{1}{\lambda}-\frac{1}{\lambda}=0$$

and as $T_e\geq 0$, and it has a zero mean, it means that almost everywhere its density function is zero, so
$$f_{T_e}(t)\stackrel{a.e.}{=}0$$
which doesn't make sense to be almost everywhere equal to zero. Is it wrong?

Comment: I answered pretty much the same question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2135428/364279). We were to find the pdf of the time since last arrival, which is what you refer to as elapsed time. We get (almost) the same exponential distribution as for the inter-arrival times.

Comment: The time between the first event after $t$ and the last event before $t$ is **not** exponential with parameter $\lambda$. One can show that its expectation converges to $2\lambda$ when $t\to\infty$. This is called the inspection paradox.

Comment: @Blaza Do you think that the solution (Your solution to the same question) is right? Since the expected value of that distribution is positive and as a result the expected value of the time between two ceonsecutive occurance is more than the expected value of the waiting time after looking at the process

Comment: @CLAUDE yes, as Did and Graham Kemp said in their comments/answers the time between the last occurrence and the next isn't exponentially distributed when we are looking from an explicit time point. As a side note, I think Did meant to write $2/\lambda$ instead of $2\lambda$. That also makes sense in a way that (as $t\to\infty$) we have 2 exponential variables for the elapsed and the wait time, so their sum gives the expectation $2/\lambda$.

Comment: @Blaza Yes. $ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let $T_e$ be the **ellapsed** time, $T_w$, the time we should **wait** for he next occurance, and $T$ be the time between two occurance. Then obviously we have
>
> $$T_e=T-T_w\Rightarrow \mathbb{E}[T_e]=\mathbb{E}[T]-\mathbb{E}[T_w]=\frac{1}{\lambda}-\frac{1}{\lambda}=0$$

To be clear: $T_e$ is the time since the last occurrence, $T_w$ is the time until the next occurrence, in a Poisson process, and $T$ is the time between the occurrences (thus $T=T_w+T_e$).

It is not obvious why you think the time-displacement, $T$, between the last and next occurrence should be *conditionally* exponentially distributed *when given* a fixed time-point that is between the occurrences (the *time of observation*).

The time between an *arbitrary* pair of subsequent occurrences is exponentially distributed.   However these are not arbitrary occurrences.

From the point of view of the last occurrence, $T$ is the time until the next occurrence given that it is after you arrive.  The time until you arrive is exponentially distributed, and the time after that until the next occurrence is also exponentially distributed, so their sum is Gamma distributed.

$$~~~~T\sim\Gamma(2,\lambda^{-1}) \\\therefore~~ \mathsf E(T)= 2\lambda^{-1}$$